# Checking for duplicate letters in an array in C

Tags: c, for-loop, duplicates, string-comparison, c-strings

I'm wondering why my duplicate check is giving me wrong output. The idea is to built a nested loop, that compares every following letter in an array, with the initial loop's one. However, if I print the results, the function gives back true when A = K e.g. and I don't understand that behaviour. Anyone able to explain what's happening here?

```
 for (int n = 0; n < strlen(argv[1]) ; n++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]) ; i++)
        {
            if (argv[1][n] == argv[1][i + 1])
            {
                printf("argv[1][n] = %c\n", argv[1][n]);
                printf("argv[1][i] = %c\n", argv[1][i]);
                printf("Error.\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "the function gives back true when A = K"? What "function"? What is "true"? Please try to create a proper [mcve] to show us and tell us the input you give and the expected as well as actual output.

Comment: And perhaps you should also take some time to refresh the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It should be `if (argv[1][n] == argv[1][i])`. Moreover, `i` should start at `int i=n+1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These for loops

```
for (int n = 0; n < strlen(argv[1]) ; n++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]) ; i++)
    {
        if (argv[1][n] == argv[1][i + 1])
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

do not make a sense because `argv[1][n]` can be the same letter at the same position as `argv[1][i+1]` because the inner loop starts from 0.

Also you are outputting a letter at position `i`

```
printf("argv[1][i] = %c\n", argv[1][i]);
```

but in the preceding if statement you are checking a letter at the position `i + 1`.

The loops can look the following way

```
for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen( argv[1] ); i < n ; i++ )
{
    for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
    {
        if ( argv[1][i] == argv[1][j] )
        {
            printf( "argv[1][i] = %c\n", argv[1][i]);
            printf( "argv[1][j] = %c\n", argv[1][j]);
            printf("Error.\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of the inner loop you could use the standard C function `strchr`. Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int unique( const char *s )
{
    while ( *s && !strchr( s + 1, *s ) ) ++s;
    
    return *s == '\0';
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s = "12345";
    
    printf( "\"%s\" -> %d\n", s, unique( s ) );
    
    s = "12341";
    
    printf( "\"%s\" -> %d\n", s, unique( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"12345" -> 1
"12341" -> 0
```

You may call the function passing as an argument the command line argument `argv[1]`. For example

```
If ( !unique( argv[1] ) ) puts( "Error." );
```

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient way to check for duplicate chars in a string.  Only requires one for-loop instead of a nested pair of loops.  Assumes an 8-bit char - hence `256` as array size.

```
size_t table[256] = {0};
size_t positions[256] = {0};
const char* sz = argv[1];

const size_t len = strlen(argv[1]);
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    unsigned char index = (unsigned char)(sz[i]);
    table[index]++;
    if (table[index] > 1)
    {
       printf("duplicate char %c found at index %d. Originally seen at index %d\n", sz[i], i, (int)(positions[index]));
       return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        positions[index] = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why A = K is because you are printing the i-th index `printf("argv[1][i] = %c\n", argv[1][i]);` when you are checking `i+1`th index `if (argv[1][n] == argv[1][i + 1])`. You are printing the wrong character that is checked with your `if` statement.

Also, be careful on that `i+1` and your loop condition.